# Schengen visa appeal successful after visit is over

Tags: visas, schengen

I had lodged an appeal against Schengen Visa refusal from Spain. Meanwhile I applied at a different Schengen state and got the visa for my visit. My visit has already been completed. Now I have come to know that my appeal is successful.

What should I do now? Will I get another visa even though I don't plan to visit Schengen area in near future (say 2019)? What is best thing to do so as to ease future visa application process?

Comment: Your question is unclear - are you asking whether it matters if you don’t use your Spain Schengen visa?

Comment: Sounds like your second visa was issued in error due to you fraudulently omitting having been denied a visa in the application.

Comment: @jwenting Nopes. Schengen VAF doesn't ask about visa refusals, removals etc. The only similar question sounds "Schengen visas issued during the past three years".

Answer (score 1):

I would keep a record of the appeal submission and the result. This will be useful as sometimes you are asked if you were ever denied a visa and you can provide this evidence that you were denied, but the rejection was reversed on appeal.

Practically though, it looks like the premise for your application is no longer valid. You have already visited the Schengen area.

Your visa (even if issued) would be invalid as your travel dates would have passed.